# ListenableFuture running on different thread

Tags: multithreading, transform, future

I am using Futures.transform and I want my ListenableFuture to run on separate thread. Is it possible to that? I see ListenableFuture has sameThreadExecutor option, is there a option to run in different thread?

Details:
I have single thread that read data from the network using some async mechanism, depending on the requests it gets it has to dispatch the request to another thread so that this thread goes back to listen more requests. I am trying to use Futures.transform to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You need an `Executor` that is not the `sameThreadExecutor`.  The most common I've seen is the cached thread pool option, but if you're doing something simple with only one other thread, you might try this:

```
final ListeningExecutorService executor = 
    MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
```

If you're looking to run a single task in another thread, calling `executor.submit()` will then run your `Callable` on another thread.  If instead you're trying to do the transformation of the future in another thread, you can pass this `executor` into `Futures.transform`.